# how to identifying Iphone incoming call and display notification?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i need to create application like identify incoming call in iphone and check that incoming call number in our database. then want to display notification what information stored in database for that particular number. These all functions want run when user receiving call.

is this possible ?

Comment: This question has been asked a gazzillion of times, the answer is NO.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Mat don't say like that .... can can we can do anything ....

Comment: maybe yes, if you enter the tag "jailbreak" in your question :)

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't for 'is this possible', it's for 'why is this not working'. Additionally, questions should actually contain a question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to start your search in [CoreTelephony](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html). That being said, if a call comes in, iOS's call-handling events will take over your app. In other words, your app will be suspended when the call comes in, and move back to the foreground when the call is complete. You can use CoreTelephony to get access to the CTCallCenter, which contains an array of CTCalls (calls in progress). CTCall does not contain the phone number for the call, to my knowledge though. Furthermore, you can't stop iOS from backgrounding your app to handle the call.

Comment: thans for your answer ... i will try. if you find any information for this question please share with me.

Comment: The answer is you can't get the information you are looking for, or respond to it in the way you want to respond. My answer supplies a way for you to get SOME call information. You will either need to rethink your approach or rethink your app.