# Detecting the call events in ios

Tags: ios, event-handling, background-process, background-foreground

I am new to ios. I was wondering if there is any way to detect the call events like incoming call, outgoing call even if my app is not in foreground. And if yes it is possible then can i read the details about that call like duration, whether it is missed, dialed or recieved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out these links .
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054706/how-to-identifying-iphone-incoming-call-and-display-notification
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html

Comment: This answer is no. Please refer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5395355/907513

Comment: As iOS 8 is not out is any way to detect the call events like incoming call, outgoing call even if my app is not in foreground. Or any other new alternatives?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes you can detect a Call. but only if your app is running in the foreground.
For this you can use the [Core Telephony Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html).

If your app will fall in any of the background running categories (VOIP, AUDIO, Location tracking or accessory ) you might be able to use the 
[`CTCallCenter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009604) in the background. But be aware that Apple will reject you app if you miss use the background running mode for something it was not meant for.

The [`CTCallCenter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009604) will allow you to detect any calls that are started or already in progress.

However you will not be able to detect any detail about the call, the [`CTCall`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CTCall) identifying the call will only tell you this state. The [`callID`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009590-CH1-DontLinkElementID_2) of [`CTCall`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CTCall) will just give you an unique identifier for the call but not the number being called.

Comment: thanks bro , but is there any way to get incoming call number or name in background state .... ?

Comment: @Mohittomar No this is not possible and would be breach of privacy.

Comment: So how are they working in this app  https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/caller-id-ringtones-hear-who/id317855277?mt=8

Comment: My guess would be that they create a custom sound, which they assign the contact as ringtone.

Comment: if we can create a caller id app or can't fetch caller info , so how TrueCaller works ? please suggest.

Comment: is same API can be used for detecting facetime calls as well?

Comment: We are able to get the information about the incoming call if app is in running mode. But when app goes to background mode it is not working for us. Is it possible in iOS8 without breaking any rules from Apple?

Comment: Unfortunately, `CTCallCenter` appears to be completely broken in iOS 9 (built with Xcode 7+) with neither the `currentCalls` property nor the `callEventHandler` working at all.