# Can I count the calls in iOS? If yes how? and If it's restricted by Apple what will be solution of it?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode5

I am stuck somewhere, I am building an application, where I want to total numbers of calls (stats) only, No Call Duration, No Number, No contact Name... Just total numbers of call, is there any way which doesn't breach apple development policy.

because accessing call history data is not allowed, is there any event which can tell us the call count, or any services which shows specific status at the time of call so we can get the status of active call and number of calls by adding them in sum.

Please have a look of my query and give me best possible answers on basis of the same.

Regards,
Andy

Comment: I think the only real option is to use *Instruments*.

Comment: There is no way with the current iOS SDK to get this information from the system. I also don't think Apple will ever allow this detail information to be accessible to developers, since this could have a serious privacy implications.

Comment: I only require count of calls with any possibility, means if there is something which starts and end with call or, change it's stats during the call and we may get the information that ok, 1 call count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no. There is no API for that.

The information you seek is located in the *Call History Database* (call_history.db)[see this wiki](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Call_History_Database). This file is very useful in forensics but cannot be accessed on a non-jailbraked iphone using legit means. More information [here](http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/) and [here](http://avi.alkalay.net/2011/12/iphone-call-history.html).

It is however, under certain conditions, possible to detect the start of a call: see [Detecting the call events in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310332/detecting-the-call-events-in-ios) on SO. You can also check the [Core Telephony Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html). This will give you ways to access **some** call informations, such the unique identifier for the call. That may be enough for you to count calls.

Comment: Thank you very very much buddy, I hope this will resolve my issue.