# In iOS 8 api is there a way to know when a user accepts a call?

Tags: ios, ios8

I'm very new to iPhone development. Sorry, if this sounds silly.I need to know if there is any method that is triggered when a user gets a call and know if he accepted or rejected it. I want to know this this on real time, and not from the logs. What is the apis thats related to these kind of functionality in ios 8.

Comment: You can only know if your app is running when the call is happening.  See [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/networkinginternet/reference/CTCallCenter/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CTCallCenter)

Comment: Core Telephony may be helpful in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18310457/188331. Also, [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html) covers the audio interruption in details, which maybe helpful for you to detect in alternative way.