# Detecting outgoing emergency call vs Developing custom dialer app

Tags: ios, events, background-process

My goal is to **listen only and not modify** the outgoing call event and send GPS coordinates to server from **background**. I'm not even interested in phone number being dialed, what I only need to know is whether the current call is Emergency call.

I've accomplished this easily in android, by following [this tutorial](http://androidlabs.org/short-experiments/broadcast-receivers/process-outgoing-calls/).

However some googling showed that, this is a big [pain in the ios world](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18310457/1451174).

The only solution I think is to write dialer app from scratch and manage all the events by myself (if that's even possible), but I think it's too overcomplicated

I'm completely new to ios and please let me know, how would you solve this problem guys?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way this will be possible on iOS unless you were planning to release and app for jailbroken phones (and even then I'm not sure it is). The Core Telphony framework has the methods you can use: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/index.html