# Which Method will be Called when phone call received while app is running?

Tags: ios

i want to know that when our App is running on iphone Device and Phone Call Received then Which Method Will be Called ?
is there Any method in appDelegate which is called after phone call recieved and our application goes to background state???

Comment: I want to detect event when phone call received while app is running.

Comment: No way you can detect if call is received..!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
// Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
// Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}
```

Comment: can u explain how it will be worked when Call Received..??Can i handle event using -applicationWillResignActive method??

Comment: Refer this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18310457/2713079   You can't do more than this.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) void (^callEventHandler)( CTCall *)
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CTCallCenter/callEventHandler)