# Determine a phone call is in progress

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to launch the iPhone camera to record only if the phone is not being used in a live call.  With my current code, if a phone call is in progress, it presents the the camera for still photos instead of video.

I would like to determine if the phone (mic) is in use and throw an alert preventing the modal presentation.

Comment: Shouldn't you just be checking to see if the microphone is currently available? You would probably have the same issue if the user is using some voice memo app, for example.

Comment: check this link:-    [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310332/detecting-the-call-events-in-ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310332/detecting-the-call-events-in-ios)