# Can I observe the incoming call and outgoing call in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, callkit

When my application is in the foreground it needs to easily detect the call event like call connected, call disconnected but when my application goes into background it does not detect any call events.

So how can I detect call events like **incoming call** and **outgoing call** in background? 
I am working on `CallKit` framework with `iOS 10` and `XCode 8`. I found that core telephony framework has been deprecated in iOS 10.

I am using the `CXCallObserverDelegate` Pattern for observing the call.

I want to calculate the call duration of incoming and outgoing calls during calling.

Comment: did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: hello saurabh are you there ?

Comment: we detect call event like  incoming call, outgoing call in background but after kill the app first time voip push ,... call kit screen apppear but my port sip not connnect .. please help me that how port sip always connnect after kill the app

Comment: @Deepesh Hello Sir, sorry for late reply..I am still finding the solution for call   event, but how can you we observe the call event in background?

Comment: @Deepesh if you find the solution please help me.

Answer (score 1):

**After searching about this question i ended up with this answer i think might help**

Yes, you can detect a Call, but only if your app is running in the foreground.
For this you can use the [Core Telephony Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html).

If your app will fall in any of the background running categories (VOIP, AUDIO, Location tracking or accessory ) you might be able to use the 
[`CTCallCenter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009604) in the background. But be aware that Apple will reject your app if you use the background running mode for something it was not meant for.

The [`CTCallCenter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009604) will allow you to detect any calls that are started or already in progress.

However, you will not be able to detect any detail about the call, the [`CTCall`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CTCall) identifying the call will only tell you this state. The [`callID`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009590-CH1-DontLinkElementID_2) of [`CTCall`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CTCall) will just give you an unique identifier for the call but not the number being called.

[original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310332/detecting-the-call-events-in-ios)