# how to read call log in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

We are developing a shopping app using xamarin forms in visual studio 2017. I need last call duration. I am new to the xamarin forms. I have been looking for couple of days but I can't find the solution, give me a suggestion to resolve the issue

Comment: Check out [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/155644/how-to-get-call-information-after-every-incoming-outgoing-call-in-the-xamarin-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin forms get call duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56494059/xamarin-forms-get-call-duration)

Comment: Were you able to access the call log?